# It has many upvotes but is this really an answer?

Tags: discussion, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I've encountered [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17528890/1519458). It has many upvotes. And it really explains a concept without being technical. However, IMHO it is not an answer to the OP's question. (It may be a good answer to another question or may be an enlightening comment.) I've flagged it as *not an answer*, and at the same time I wonder what you think.

Comment: It is answering by analogy. It explains the differences very succinctly, IMO. And doesn't go into the question of "which is best" (and rightly so - it entirely depends on the circumstances). What's the problem exactly? That it is short?

Comment: @Oded Being short is not an issue.

Comment: OK. But what is the issue then?

Comment: It's definitely an answer, insofar as it attempts to answer the question. You may feel that it isn't a *good* answer, in which case downvote and move on.

Comment: Well, @Oded The question asks clearly "which is the preferred and why". (And as I said IMHO it is a good comment, or may be a good answer to another question.) And this so called answer does not attempt to answer any of these questions (which and why). It gives a good analogy, I agree. However this is a useful information about the topic, not an answering attempt  And I think it is better as a comment.

Comment: But it **does** attempt to answer the question. It gives an analogy to each usage.

Comment: I think it is the orange in this post http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: "it really explains a concept without being technical", You've even said yourself it explains what the difference is, it is an answer because it explains in a single sentence why you might want to use either version without adding an opinion

Comment: @Sayse in that respect, I can see the point.